# $h: G \to H$ and $f: G \to K$ such that $\ker f \subset \ker h $ but there is no homomorphism $g : K \to H$ such that $h = g \circ f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I just saw the fundamental theorem of morphisms, and I was wondering: Is there an example of two homomorphisms $h: G \to H$ and $f: G \to K$ such that $\ker f \subset \ker h $ but there is no homomorphism $g : K \to H$ such that $h = g \circ f$?

Is anyone is able to give me a hint about the existence of those homomorphisms?

Comment: Do you mean to suppose that $f$ is onto?

Comment: I supposed nothing about f on onto or one-to-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: let $G=H=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ with $h$ the identity map, $K=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$, and $k$ the only nontrivial homomorphism from $G$ to $K$, which sends $1\pmod 2$ to $2\pmod 4$.